Выбор даты в QCalendarWidget правой кнопкой мыши с одновременным выводом контекстного меню
Не могу решить вопрос с выбором даты в календаре правой кнопкой мыши. 
Когда пользователь наводить курсор на определенную дату, нажимает правую кнопку мыши, то дата выделяется и появляется контекстное меню. 
Предполагаю, что нужно переопределить метод mousePressEvent(), но не могу понять, как это сделать?
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QCalendarWidget, QMenu, QAction


class MyCalendar(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu_for_cal = QMenu()
        menu_for_cal.addAction(QAction('First_action', self))
        menu_for_cal.addAction(QAction('Second_action', self))
        menu_for_cal.exec(event.globalPos())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print("Left Button Clicked")
        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            print("Right Button Clicked")


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Координаты и события")
        self.resize(300, 200)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.cal = MyCalendar(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cal, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


Как вариант
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint, QModelIndex, QDate
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, \
    QCalendarWidget, QMenu, QAction, QApplication, QTableView


class MyCalendar(QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setVerticalHeaderFormat(QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader)
        self.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
# +++      
        self.press_date = QDate()                                    # +++

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        childrens = self.children()                                  # +++
        for ch in childrens:
            if isinstance(ch, QTableView): 
                index = ch.indexAt(event.pos() - QPoint(0, 20))
                day = ch.model().data(index)
                self.press_date = QDate(
                    self.yearShown(), self.monthShown(), day)
                print(self.press_date)                               #
                self.setSelectedDate(self.press_date)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        menu_for_cal = QMenu()
        menu_for_cal.addAction(QAction('First_action', self))
        menu_for_cal.addAction(QAction('Second_action', self))
        menu_for_cal.exec(event.globalPos())

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        super().paintCell(painter, rect, date)
        if date == self.press_date:
            painter.setBrush(QColor(122, 27, 181, 50))
            painter.drawRect(rect)
            painter.setBrush(Qt.red)
            painter.drawEllipse(rect.topLeft() + QPoint(5, 5    ), 3, 3) 
        else:
            QCalendarWidget.paintCell(self, painter, rect, date)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.cal = MyCalendar(self)
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.cal, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle("Координаты и события")
    window.resize(300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



Спасибо! Разобрался. Все работает отлично. Единственный вопрос: почему координаты именно такие event.pos() - QPoint(0, 20) в строке index = ch.indexAt(event.pos() - QPoint(0, 20))

@NikV пожалуйста. Sorry, я не смотрел почему координаты немного сдвинуты, а сделал так как надо.

Предполагаете правильно. Для начала, стоит посмотреть как работает стандартная реализация. Если при клике ПКМ, дата выделяется, то достаточно вызвать оригинальный метод, а на условие (как у вас уже сделано), необходимо вызывать QMenu в позиции клика мыши.
PS: сперва не обратил внимание на ваш метод для вызова меню. В таком случае, вы можете вызывать непосредственно его, разве что у методов разные Eventы передаются

При клике мышкой по дате print("Left Button Clicked") и print("Right Button Clicked") не срабатывают. Условия срабатывают только при клике по заголовку, где указан месяц и год.
